# What does the :: (scope resolution operator) do in this program?

Tags: c++

I am currently learning C++ and saw this program when I was reading a book.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double counter = 50;

int main(){

for(int counter = 1; counter != 10; ++counter){
  printf("%d\n",::counter/counter);
}

}
```

Now, I read up on the Scope Resolution Operator and I thought that this would print out the global variable counter divided by the local variable counter. However, the program prints out this:

> 2094374456
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758
>
> 4195758

What are these numbers and what does the Scope Resolution Operator do in this case?

Disclaimer: I do not know C, but I have extensive experience in Java.

Comment: You got the `::` right. The problem is that you are printing a `double` with `%d`.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings and it should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: For `c++` use `std::cout` which is type safe instead of `printf` and it would have printed the value correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used wrong format specifier. `::counter` will be the global `counter`, whose type is `double`, so the result fo division will have type `double` and it should be printed via `%f` format specifier or other specifier that calls for double such as `%g`.

Passing data having wrong type will invoke *undefined behavior* in C, but I'm not sure about C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double counter = 50;

int main(){

    for(int counter = 1; counter != 10; ++counter){
      printf("%f\n",::counter/counter);
    }

}
```

Comment: C doesn't have namespaces or scope resolution, but even in C++, using the wrong format specifier is still undefined behavior.  But since this code is using C++ by virtue of scope resolution, it would be better to re-write the code using `std::cout` instead of `printf()`, then there is no possibility of a type mismatch: `#include <iostream> ... std::cout << ::counter/counter << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

`::counter` does indeed refer to the global variable `counter`. The problem with this code is that the result of the division is of type `double` since one of the arguments is, and a `double` value is being passed to an ellipsis where `int` is expected since the format specifier is `%d`. This results in undefined behaviour. You need to change it to `%f`.

Comment: If the compiler warnings are turned on it will probably warn about this too.

Comment: @TomKeddie: that depends on whether the compiler actually supports parsing of printf-style format strings in variadic functions at compile-time.  Not all C++ compilers do.

Comment: OK.  Thanks.  I am doing this with a raspberry pi and it compiled without error. Weird how the book messed up with the printf